# setState update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const BtnBox = styled.ul`
display:flex;
width:50vw;
align-items:center;
justify-content:flex-start;
font-weight:900;
font-size:5vw;
letter-spacing:-0.5vw;
`;
const MyBtn = styled.li`
width:30%;
font-size:5vw;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:flex-start;
cursor:pointer;
`;

class SignAndLog extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { Scolor: 'black', Lcolor: 'grey' };
    this.chooseFun = this.chooseFun.bind(this);
    localStorage.setItem('fuck', this.state.Scolor);
  }


  chooseFun(e) {
    const myName = e.target.dataset.name;
    if (myName === 'sign') {
      this.setState({
        Scolor: 'black',
        Lcolor: 'grey'
      });
      localStorage.setItem('status', myName);
    } else {
      this.setState({
        Scolor: 'grey',
        Lcolor: 'black'
      });
      localStorage.setItem('status', myName);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BtnBox>
        <MyBtn onClick={this.chooseFun} data-name="sign" style={{ color: this.state.Scolor }}>註冊</MyBtn>
        <MyBtn onClick={this.chooseFun} data-name="log" style={{ color: this.state.Lcolor }}>登入</MyBtn>
      </BtnBox>
    );
  }
}


export default SignAndLog;
```

And when I click both my MyBtn , it always not work , and in F12 console area shows that:

> app.js:3880 Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or
>   mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an
>   unmounted component. This is a no-op.

Please check the code for the SignAndLog component.

Can any body tell me where I should fix?

PS:due to my ESlint , I cannot `console.log()` , so I use `localStorage.setItem` to be my `console.log()`

Comment: Are you by any chance clicking the buttons almost simultaneously?

Comment: This could be related to the parent component unmounting when you click one of those buttons

Comment: @OP, please validate Saif's answer and comment accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

follow this [article](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/callback-functions-in-react-e822ebede766)! and you will get better understanding of how to setState.

I prefer to use the fat arrow function.
try this out!

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const BtnBox = styled.ul`
display:flex;
width:50vw;
align-items:center;
justify-content:flex-start;
font-weight:900;
font-size:5vw;
letter-spacing:-0.5vw;
`;
const MyBtn = styled.li`
width:30%;
font-size:5vw;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:flex-start;
cursor:pointer;
`;

class SignAndLog extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { Scolor: 'black', Lcolor: 'grey' };
    localStorage.setItem('fuck', this.state.Scolor);
  }


  chooseFun =(e)=> {
    const myName = e.target.dataset.name;
    if (myName === 'sign') {
      this.setState({
        Scolor: 'black',
        Lcolor: 'grey'
      });
      localStorage.setItem('status', myName);
    } else {
      this.setState({
        Scolor: 'grey',
        Lcolor: 'black'
      });
      localStorage.setItem('status', myName);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BtnBox>
        <MyBtn onClick={(e)=>this.chooseFun(e)} data-name="sign" style={{ color: this.state.Scolor }}>註冊</MyBtn>
        <MyBtn onClick={(e)=>this.chooseFun(e)} data-name="log" style={{ color: this.state.Lcolor }}>登入</MyBtn>
      </BtnBox>
    );
  }
}


export default SignAndLog;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with binding context to functions (arrow functions). This has something to do with updating state during a rendering, which is not allowed in react.

Comment: Because it works does not mean it is the right way to do things or is answering the question

Comment: please when you say something **you have to be sure**. there are many ways to check your information before giving the vote down. please read this article:  (https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/callback-functions-in-react-e822ebede766).

Comment: I actually am sure about what I'm talking about. The person asking the question got this error: `app.js:3880 Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.` And this error has nothing to do with arrow functions. It has something to do with setting a state for a component that is mounting or has unmounted

Comment: @SaifAlradhi The mistake you pointed out is absolutely correct. `onClick={this.chooseFunc}` will not bind the context to call `this.setState`. Using an arrow function is the way. Although `onClick={this.chooseFunc}` is sufficient since you made `chooseFunc` into an arrow function. However as for the user's warning error, it's pretty weird, firstly the code he provided will not lead to such error and secondly the error should no more be showing up.

Comment: Why not if in the constructor there is this line of code `this.chooseFun = this.chooseFun.bind(this);`?